# Effect of changing of the concentration of reactants when concentration of the initiator and the concentration of the initial reactant are very small

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, polymers

A + I---> p

What happens to the rate of the reaction when the concentration of the reactant is changed in a system that its concentration of its initiator and the concentration of the initial reactant is very small? Generally, we add a small amount of initiators with respect to the concentration of reactance.eg: I= 1*10^-4M, A= 1M

Can we take the order of A zero under these conditions?

For example, styrene polymerization is initiated by benzoyl peroxide.

| styrene used (mmol) | benzoyl peroxide (mmol) |
| --- | --- |
| 0.45 | 1.5 |
| 0.93 | 2.48 |
| 2.27 | 1.5 |

Comment: Why do you think you could?

Comment: It is because the reaction is likely limited by the concentration of the initiator. Generally we add small amount of initiators respect to the concentration of reactance.

Comment: Try to reformulate the question as the scenario is not very clear. Be aware that posts containing just questions are not good posts. // Review the guides [Asking](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) and [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Not following the guidance may lead to lack of satisfying answers, misunderstanding, objections, question down-voting or even question closure.

Comment: Is it a kind of polymerization, like e.g. styrene polymerization initiated by benzoyl peroxide?

Comment: Yes. exactly styrene polymerization initiated by benzoyl peroxide

Comment: Sorry my bad, I reformulated the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145528/discussion-between-poutnik-and-kavindu-lochana).

Answer (score 1):

As you written the reaction in an irreversible fashion, that will be my starting point. You cannot state that the partial order of $A$ is zero, still the rate law has the form
$$ r = kC_A^\alpha C_I^\beta \tag{1} $$
However, if you put an excess of $A$, then its concentration as the reaction takes places, will not deviate much from the initial concentration $C_{A0}$. Thus, Eq. (1) now is
$$ r = \underbrace{kC_{A0}^\alpha}_{k'} C_I^\beta = k'C_I^\beta \tag{2} $$
Eq. (2) is helpful because it allows to at least determine $\beta$ in this limiting case. For example, if you have data, you can couple Eq. (2) with a mole balance in a batch reactor at constant volume
\begin{align}
  \frac{dC_I}{dt} &= r_I \\
  \frac{dC_I}{dt} &= -\nu_Ir \\
  \frac{dC_I}{dt} &= -k'C_I^\beta \rightarrow
  \ln\left(-\dfrac{dC_I}{dt}\right) = \ln(k') + \beta\ln(C_I) \tag{3}
\end{align}
If you have $C_I$ as a function of time, you can plot the left-hand sight (by numerical differentiation of your data) vs $\ln(C_I)$. If it results in a straight line, then the slope and the y-intercept will inform you that
$$ k' = \exp(b) \hspace{1 cm} m = \beta \tag{4,5}$$
Eq. (4) won't give you anything valuable, since $ k' = kC_{A0}^\alpha $, and we don't know $\alpha$. However, at least you have $\beta$ for this set of experiments.

If the reaction mechanism is more complicated, as Poutnik pointed out, then the algebra changes. However, you can always approximate at every step that $C_A \approx C_{A0}$ to simplify matters.